# Python: pass external argument to function inside of a class

Tags: python, class, compiler-errors

I have the following class in Python:

```
class myclass():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def dosomething1(self):
        #Do your thing
    def dosomething2(self):
        #Do your thing
```

I need to pass `dosomething1` a random number as an argument, but when I change my code to this:

```
class myclass():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def dosomething1(self,random_number):
        #Do your thing
    def dosomething2(self):
        #Do your thing
```

my compiler says that `random_number` is not defined. I intend to pass that number from outside the class, eg by doing:

```
result = myclass.dosomething1(random_number)
```

Why is my compiler complaining? Where else inside the class should I define `random_number`?

Comment: Quite strange. Can you show the exact error message?

Comment: @MoosaSaadat it is a message shown by Spyder before I even run the code, eg `Undefined name 'random_number' (pyflakes E)`

Comment: try `myclass()`. You need to create an instance of the class. Which is achivied by using the brackets.

Comment: Error doesnt seem related to class definition. Make sure you test defining the class and using the class seperately